# How to use Parameter to read element in XML file using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, parameters, arguments

I want to read element in XML file using parameters. I tried this code, I can print the XML file, but I can't get the element. But I tried to get the element without using  parameters and It works.

```
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$XML
)

$Feature= Get-Content $XML
$Feature
$Read_XML = $Feature.DocumentElement.InnerText
$Read_XML
```

I run the script from cmd :

```
$PowerShell.exe getxml.ps1 -XML <path xml file>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks @OcasoProtal

Comment: Ok, made it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `$Feature` to xml:

```
[xml]$Feature= Get-Content $XML
```